# Search Pattern Frequency

Tags: php, frequency, phrase

Preferably PHP solutions -- but any ideas would be great.

Give a text blob

'This is a super string of some content whree I want to find red sweaters and purple elephants.  The purple elephants will count twice. and the red sweaters will count 3 times since red sweaters occurs three times'

and a phrase list

'red sweaters, purple elephants'

want to search the text blob and return count of occurances

therefore

red sweaters = 3
and purple elephants = 2

Comment: http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Is this Homework? If yes, tag appropriately! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$string = 'This is a super string of some content whree I want to find red sweaters and purple elephants. The purple elephants will count twice. and the red sweaters will count 3 times since red sweaters occurs three times';

$keys = 'red sweaters, purple elephants';

$pkeys = explode(', ', $keys);
foreach($pkeys as $key)
{
    printf("%s occourrences: %d\n", $key, substr_count($string, $key));
}
```

Comment: DaNieL - thanks.. I think I was over-engineering it!!   Do you think that there is a benegit to substr_count over preg_match ?

Comment: substr_count works differents from preg_match_all function - as noticed by amosrivera, substr_count() will hit, in you case, even brownred sweaters becose contain the string you use as needle. With preg_match_all you can define more complex (and precise) rules, for example you can do a case-insensitive search without modify the original string (as suggested Nick).. all depends on what do you need to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) which will search for strings inside a text. Just note that in your example if the text was "brownred sweaters" that will count +1 for "red sweaters".

You can also use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Something like `preg_match("/$string/",$text);`. This would return the times the string was found.

Also if you want to search for several strings delimited by a comma (like your example) you first need to split the string. You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this. `$strings = explode(",",$search);`

Comment: +1 for a more detailed answer than mine; even if regexp looks a bit overkill in this situation for me, your answer offer more solutions ;)

Comment: @DaNieL funny because i had upvoted your answer for being more straight forward ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
  $string = strtolower('This is a super string of some content whree I want to find red sweaters and purple elephants. The purple elephants will count twice. and the red sweaters will count 3 times since red sweaters occurs three times');

  $allprases = 'red sweaters, purple elephants'

  $phrasearray = explode(',',$allphrases);

  foreach ($phrasearray as $k => $phrase) {
    $phrase = strtolower(trim($phrase));
    echo 'String '.$phrase.' found '.substr_count($string,$phrase).' times.<br />';
  }
?>
```

Do note that substr_count is case sensitive (which is why I'm strtolower()ing everything in the above code). This can be removed easily enough so that the code above is case sensitive too.